# Apple's MFi licensee Accessory with classic Bluetooth communicate with app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

We have license MFi accessory which let us connect with iOS app. accessory uses Bluetooth® Version 2.1 SPP pro le HID Pro le Apple iAP2/MFi

So my app should be using external framework to connect to classic Bluetooth device.

I've read about FAQ and rest of details. It's confusing and I did not get a 100% answer to my only question.

Since we have to create app which communicates to MFi accessory , via Classic Bluetooth do we need to enrolled for MFi license because we have to use external framework? Or we do not have to enrolled for MFi program and can directly use framework with SDK accessory offering as it is MFi license accessory?

Comment: Is your Accessory already licensed? Did you used your technical ticket for your developer account to get an answer?

Comment: yes we have purchased MFi accessory licensed one. it does have HF classic bluetooth for connectivity. i have to developed app which will connect to accessory.

Comment: So.. this answers your question?

Comment: i read on forum those who wants to use external framework for classic bluetooth device have to enrolled for MFi program. so i was confused as do we too have to enrolled ...?

Answer (score 1):

We have helped multiple MFi device guys with their BT needs.
Our new BT53 has the very latest iAP2 protocol pre-loaded into the module.
You do need to be an MFi member to allow you tp purchase the Apple CP before you can take advantage of our BT53 with iAP2.
We're seeing speed BLE speed = speed is about 30,000 bps
Our IAP2 FW can run about 500,000 bps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have enrolled to the MFi program to be able to connect with bluetooth in your iOS app. I've developed a bluetooth app without the MFi program and got accepted. BUT I was required to send a hard copy of the accessory to Apple to get approved in the review proces of the app.

The MFi program has some pro's, the documentation helps you with connecting to an Apple device, you can ask more technical questions then with a standard Apple Developer Account and it shows customers your product meets the standards of Apple.